# Accordion - sometimes item needs double click

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm using this accordion code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION   
$('div.accordionButton').click(function() {
    if($(this).data("slided") === true) {
        $(this).next().slideUp('normal');
        $(this).data("slided", false);
    } else {
        $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');    
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        $(this).data("slided", true);
    }
});

//HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD    
$("div.accordionContent").hide();

});
```

I noticed that sometimes item needs to be clicked twice to get it expanded.

Here is working [JFIDDLE example](http://jsfiddle.net/SUDHARSHAN_R/9RKkC/)
You can test it by clicking all items from top to bottom and after that try clicking from bottom to top -> Item needs double click to work.

Any ideas/solution how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set slided value to false

```
    if($(this).data("slided") === true) {
        $(this).next().slideUp('normal');
        $(this).data("slided", false);
    } else {
              $('div.accordionButton').data('slided',false); //this line
        $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');    
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        $(this).data("slided", true);
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9RKkC/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a data properties on slide up when you click on the element, but when an element close because of a click on an other element, you are not changing the data. Your condition then evaluate to true and slide up the accordion already hidden.

Change the data atrribute in the else statement :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION   
    $('div.accordionButton').click(function() {
        if($(this).data("slided") === true) {
            $(this).next().slideUp('normal');
            $(this).data("slided", false);
        } else {
            $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');
            $('div.accordionButton').data("slided", false); //Here
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
            $(this).data("slided", true);
        }
    });

    //HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD    
    $("div.accordionContent").hide();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9RKkC/3/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display: none;` from `.accordionContent`:

```
.accordionContent { 
    width: 800px;
    float: left;
    background: #95B1CE;
}
```

Or the other try is with the logic, just a simple change:

```
if($(this).data("slided") === true) {
    $(this).next().slideUp('normal');
    $(this).data("slided", false);
} else {
    $('div.accordionButton').data('slided', false);
    $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');    
    $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
    $(this).data("slided", true);
}
```

Comment: This seems an odd suggestion. Accordions don't typically start with all panels visible. The inline style set by `.hide()`, `.slideDown()`, etc. would override it.

Comment: True, but if that's the one causing the issue! We can have a `hidden` class and do a `.hide().removeClass('hidden')`